# Server Error 500 .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, shared-hosting

I have this working on my dedicated server but it fails on my shared hosting please what can be wrong? Thank you.

## AddHandler phpini-cgi .php

```
#Action phpini-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-custom-ini.cgi

Options -Indexes

Options  FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php


# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?q=$1 [L] 
 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?q=$1&r=$2 [L]
 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?q=$1&r=$2&s=$3 [L]
 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?q=$1&r=$2&s=$3&t=$4 [L]
 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the problem. I noticed the hosting company do not configure Php to display error thus making it difficult for you to know where the problem is. The problem is actually the database connection to the server. Once I fix the database connection my website came on fine.